# How to configure MacVim to quit on exit?

Tags: macos, gvim, macvim, gvimrc

When I close MacVim using the standard vim command `:q`, the MacVim window closes, but the program is still running. This causes trouble when other processes try to spawn an instance of MacVim, because if it is still running, a special flag needs to be passed to MacVim so that a new instance is opened, but then the instances accumulate.

Is there a way using vimscript to kill the process as well as close the window upon exit?

Answer (score 21):

If you consistently end up with multiple *MacVim* icons in your *Dock*, then you might want to examine how you are starting *MacVim*. Specifically, `:help macvim-start` says

> Do NOT call the MacVim binary inside the app bundle to start MacVim.

From the command line, you would normally use either `open -a MacVim filename` or `mvim filename`<sup>1</sup>. From the GUI, you can associate *MacVim* with particular extensions, drag-and-drop files onto *MacVim* in *Finder* or the *Dock* or into an open *MacVim* window, or you can use the Services menu to start new buffers with selections from other applications. There is also the `mvim://` URL handler (see `:help mvim://`).

None of these methods require any special flags/options whether an existing instance is running or not and should ever create an extra *MacVim* icon in the *Dock*.

<sup>1</sup> *mvim* is a script that comes with *MacVim*; see `:help mvim`. Once you have it installed in a directory in your PATH, then you can use it to edit files in an existing *MacVim* instance (or will launch one if it was not already running).

---

The “After last window closes:” **Quit MacVim** option in the General tab of *MacVim*’s preferences (⌘, or **MacVim** > **Preferences…**) may be what you want.

If you really need something more specific, then you can use the *MacVim*-custom command `:macaction terminate:` to ask the whole *MacVim* application to exit at any scriptable moment. It should be equivalent to ⌘Q  and the **MacVim** > **Quit MacVim** menu item (they all send the `terminate:` action to the application’s first responder); if you have modified buffers, then it will ask you if you want to “Quit anyway?”.

It sounds like you might want to hook it up to the VimLeave event through an autocommand:

```
autocmd VimLeave * macaction terminate:
```

Comment: Ah, finally my Vim dock icon goes away once I close all buffers :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the MacVim bundle from [macvim-dev](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim) doesn't have the mvim script. I took the mvim script from [b4winckler](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim) repo and it is sort of working as described above.